# Selecting fields from Contact based on Account subquery?

Tags: soql, workbench

I would like to return all related contact names based on a specific set of accounts returned via a subquery, but keep receiving a `MALFORMED_QUERY` error. Running the following SOQL in Workbench is yielding an error:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.Id IN
(
    SELECT Parent.Id
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name LIKE '%--this--%' OR Name LIKE '%--that--%'
    GROUP BY Parent.Id
)
```

Note that I am using the `GROUP BY` statement so that I can return a list of unique values, as SOQL does not use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subquery would be if you flipped your query around and had something like the following example found on the help docs [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm):

> Query parent-to-child, which are almost always one-to-many. Specify
>   these relationships using a subquery (enclosed in parentheses), where
>   the initial member of the FROM clause in the subquery is related to
>   the initial member of the outer query FROM clause. Note that for
>   subqueries, you should specify the plural name of the object as that
>   is the name of the relationship for each object.
>
> For example:

```
SELECT Name,
      (
        SELECT Name
        FROM Models__r
      )
    FROM Widget__c
```

> The query returns the name for all the Widgets, and for each Widget,
>   the name of each Model.

What you are attempting above is more like a semi-join as described [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm):

> ID field Semi-Join
>
> You can include a semi-join in a WHERE clause:
>       SELECT Id, Name
>       FROM User
>       WHERE Id IN
>       (
>         SELECT OwnerId
>         FROM Widget__c
>         WHERE Name = 'Ring'
>       )
>
> This is a parent-to-child semi-join from User to Widget. Notice that
>   the left operand, OwnerId, of the IN clause is an ID field. The
>   subquery returns a single field of the same type as the field to which
>   it is compared. A full list of restrictions that prevent unnecessary
>   processing is provided at the end of this section.

So basically, you do not need to worry about the distinct, since the returned ids are just used to filter the contacts you are getting.

Also noticed the you are using Account.Id and Parent.Id, try the following:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name LIKE '%--this--%' OR Name LIKE '%--that--%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jenny explained you don't need the GROUP BY clause, so get rid of it.

Your inner select field (Parent.id) can't have more than one level of relationship so change it to ParentId (You don't need the "." dot).

Finally the "left operand 'Account.Id' also cannot have more than one level of relationship so change it to AccountId (Again you don't need the "." dot).

So your final query should look something like the following.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name LIKE '%--this--%' OR Name LIKE '%--that--%'
)
```